# Facebook Page Plugin - Nothing Appearing besides text in title?

Tags: html, css, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have attempted to add the Facebook Page Plugin to the website I am making with dreamweaver. This is the code I have.

```html
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>
  <div class="fb-page" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/matteosforries" data-width="350" data-height="550" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="false" data-show-posts="true">
    <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
      <blockquote cite="http://www.facebook.com/matteosforries"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/matteosforries">di Matteos</a>
      </blockquote>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

How do I make it appear on my browser? The page is a fan page, not a private profile. Thankyou.

Comment: Check your browser’s error console.

Comment: I checked your code and I can see the page plugin correctly. It could be an issue with your browser - just to make sure I'd recommend that you are using the latest version of whatever version you are using.